# No soft-keyboard present when custom input device (registered via /dev/uinput) is present

Tags: android, android-ndk, keyboard

I developed a custom input (using `/dev/uniput`) to input remote characters to the device. On some devices (Nexus 7, for instance), soft-keyboard is not shown if the uinput devices registers that it handles QWERTY keys. Through experimentation, I found that if I register just keys `0` - `9`, than the soft keyboard is shown and in addition to that, I can "inject" keys `0` - `9`. If I register additional keys (QWERTY), the soft keyboard is not shown anymore.

The registration is done using `ioctl(m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, key)` where `m_fd` is open `/dev/uinput` device and key is linux key code for a key that this device is supposed to support.

This is a problem since most accented characters can not be input otherwise (like `€`, `Ç`, `Â`, etc) - they can be (using the software keyboard), if the soft keyboard is present.

Is there perhaps a "registration switch" of some sort to tell android-platform to leave the soft-keyboard appearing when user input is required (i.e. on EditText focus)?

Comment: Have you tried alternative keyboards (such as Swype or Swiftkey)?  There's a function in the keyboard software that decides whether to show or not, the default keyboard I believe hides itself if a hardware keyboard is present.  That's google's expected behavior.  I know that at least at one time I made Swype appear if a keyboard existed and it was a front face keyboard.  I don't know if that code still exists in the codebase or not though.  Which is another thought-  add yourself as a hidden keyboard may work, if it doesn't block your input (it would think you were a closed slide out kb).

Comment: Gabe, I have not tried Swype or Swiftkey, as the app must work with all types of keyboards. I'll look into keyboard registration files to see if I can circumvent this somehow. Some devices allow you to "disable HW keyboard" and then you get the soft keyboard back. But N7, for instance, does not.

Comment: Then I think you're kind of stuck (although it may be worth trying just for confirmation).  The decision to hide the soft keyboard or not is the soft keyboard's choice-  it returns true or false from onEvaluateInputViewShown.  The evaluation criteria are up to the keyboard itself.  If it decides that if there's a keyboard it shouldn't appear, then it won't appear.

Comment: If I enable more than one input method (i.e. google hinduin addition to the default keyboard, I can then see "Choose input method" in the notifications. There, I can "disable" the hardware keyboard (that actually does not prevent the uinput device to stop functioning), which brings up the built-in google keyboard. This does not solve the original problem, but it is a workaround to enter accented characters. Accented characters can be entered using the hardware keyboard if an appropriate layout is chosen for the hardware keyboard (using the Settings -> Language and Input configuration screens).